# I want to have borders( lines) that separate the elements in my navbar

Tags: html, css

I can't get borders between my elements in my navigation bar.

I tried adding this to the CSS `.navli` selector:

```
border-bottom:1px solid grey;
```

but the lines don't go all the way in the navbar.

```css
#navhead {
  margin: 15 20;
}

.navul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navli {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10;
  margin-left: -10;
  padding-bottom: 24;
}

.navbar {
  border: solid grey;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="left">
    <header id=navhead>JS Documentation</header>
    <ul class="navul">
      <li class="navli"><a class="nav-link" href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
      <li class="navli"><a><a class="nav-link" href="#What_you_should_already_know">What you should already know</a></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navli"><a class="nav-link" href="#JavaScript_and_Java">JavaScript and Java
</a></li>
      <li class="navli"><a class="nav-link" href="#Hello_World">Hello world</a></li>
      <li class="navli"><a class="nav-link" href="#Variables">Variables</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Because `ul` has padding applied. Remove that and your `li` elements will take full width of `ul`

Comment: Please not that you have a few issues in your code. Your code is not valid and semantically incorrect. For once you used: `<a><a class="nav-link" href="#What_you_should_already_know">What you should already know</a></a>`. You can't nest an anchor in an anchor (which makes no sense). `<header>` can not (should not) be a part of the `<nav>` It makes sense to have it vice-versa. also `<header>` is an element to be shown at the very top of a document not on the side (`<aside>`). In any case it is not to be used a headline (`<h1>`).

Comment: `.navli {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10;
  margin-left: -10;
  padding-bottom: 24;
}` missing values such as `px`. Instead of adding a negative margin you could (should)  simply just remove the default margin and padding of the `ul`.